# Getting EADDRINUSE error while running stream analytics job locally in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to run a stream analytics job locally in VS code. I am getting this error "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8999 : Port 8999 is already used by another local credential server"
[image]

I tried to find the process using the port by " netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr "8999" and I have killed the process with PID. There was only one item showing. But still this error keep coming.

I am not sure how to resolve. Are there any detailed logs available for VS code or anyway I can try another port number.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pinging the internal team on that one, it's the first time of hearing of it. This will take some time, sorry about it.

Comment: Hey @Binil, could you let me know which version ASA Tools extension you are using in VS Code? Also if you have multiple VS Code open running jobs simultaneously? And if you potentially also use Visual Studio side by side with VS Code, running jobs simultaneously? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, The ASA Version is 1.1.3. I tried the project with Visual studio and Code also but not simultaneous. Now I have started using with Visual studio since VS code is giving this issue. Its working fine in VS

Comment: This will be a long poll on our side, as we can't reproduce. We will be considering adding a setting for the credential server port next planning cycle (no ETA).

Comment: By the way, had you try killing all the processes with port 8999, and running it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run your stream analytics job using the latest ASA version and see if this error still occurs.

Comment: In the new version its not happening